# multiple complex .htaccess RewriteRules

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I need help setting up the `RewriteRules` in my `.htaccess` file. I need to first check for any existing files, then some custom rewrites, and if any of those doesn'y match rewrite it to `index.php`.

My current `.htaccess`, located in the document root, file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# Don't rewrite existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# Custom rewrites
# TODO: Don't know how to make these work
# RewriteRule ^/css/style\.css$  /css/style.css.php [L,NC,QSA]
# RewriteRule ^/js/config\.js$   /js/config.js.php [L,NC,QSA]
# RewriteRule ^/js/post\.js$     /js/post.js.php [L,NC,QSA]

# If any of the above don't match hand it to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]

php_value upload_max_filesize 10485760
php_value post_max_size 10485760
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have it this way:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Custom rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^(?:css/style\.css|js/(?:config|post)\.js)$ $0.php [L,NC]

# Don't rewrite existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# If any of the above don't match hand it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This is the new rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:css/style\.css|js/(?:config|post)\.js)$ $0.php [L,NC]
```

Which matches `/css/style.css` or `/js/config.js` or `/js/post.js` and added `.php` in the end of these URIs. `$0` is back-reference of the complete match.